# batch to delete user in text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like help with creating script that deletes all users from the output (**list.txt**) after I run this:

```
cmd Udadmin –list >> C:\temp\list.txt
```

To delete the users I use this:

```
cmd udadmin -f XDT_PLT_UD -user testusr –delete
```

The Ouput looks something like this.

the output file looks something like this 
t10user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t11user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t12user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t13user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t14user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t15user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t1user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t20user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
Once I have constructed the script I will post on

But the list could be several hundred and I do not want to be deleting the list of users manually.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: could you *please* format your output file properly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file contains one username (and nothing but the username) on each line, you can use the `for /f` command to read each line from the file (type `for /?` for help):

```
for /f "delims=" %%u in (C:\temp\list.txt) do (
    udadmin -f XDT_PLT_UD -user %%u –delete
)
```

EDIT: Following your comment that each line would contain several usernames, then the following should work, assuming the usernames are separated by whitespace and that there are no spaces contained in any username:

```
rem %%L is a line and %%U is a username within the line
for /f "delims=" %%L in (C:\temp\list.txt) do (
    for %%U in (%%L) do udadmin -f XDT_PLT_UD -user %%U –delete
)
```

Comment: Thank you the output file would contain several user name on each line.

Comment: the output file looks something like this
 t10user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t11user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t12user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t13user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t14user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t15user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t1user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t20user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t3user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t5user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t6user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t8user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521 
t9user XDT_PLT_UD 2018.0521

once I have constructed the script I will post on here

Comment: Unfortunately comments don't preserve line separators, so I can't see where one line ends and a new line begins. It's better to edit the original question.